# Add permission in folder via SharePoint Web Services

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, web-services, wss

Is it possible to add or update permission in folder or sub-folder in WSS 3.0 with Web Services?

Now, I created the folder inside list(document library) and the permission inherit from parent but I need to add new permission in folder inside list.

The /_vti_bin/permissions.asmx not allow to add permission in folder level.

How should I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AddPermissions method of the Permissions Web Service can only be used to add Permissions to a Site or a List and NOT for the folder inside a List. For more clarity check the Microsoft documentation on [Permissions.AddPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/permissions.permissions.addpermission.aspx) Web Method.

Comment: But item level permission functionality available in share point right. then how they achieve it without web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just go to the Manage Permissions in the Folder's context menu. Then on the manage permissions page select Edit Permissions, it will break the inheritance, then you can add / remove groups to the folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I mean How I add permission with the SP Web Services not add it with SP site directly.

Comment: Far enough to realise it was a waste of time to ever use them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have something on the following information

public void AddPermission // you can use this for adding permissions in a web site i think you can use it on a sharepoint to but i dont know it for sure
(
    string objectName,
    string objectType,
    string permissionIdentifier,
    string permissionType,
    int permissionMask
)